# Running a non-standard cron job

Tags: cron

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

I would like to run a PHP script /home/app/myapp.php at minute 37 every two hours between 5AM and 7PM GMT Monday through Friday year round.

What is the crontab file syntax for that?

Comment: I don't see what's non-standard about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
37 5-19/2 * * 1-5
```

Since, quoting the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/crontab.5):

```
  field          allowed values
  -----          --------------
  ...
  day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)

Ranges of numbers are allowed.  Ranges are two numbers separated with a hyphen.    
...    
Step  values  can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with ``/<number>'' specifies skips of the number's value through the range.

Names can also be used for the ``month'' and ``day of week'' fields.  ...  Ranges or lists of names are not allowed.
```